# Memoir Subappendices without chapter number

Tags: numbering, memoir, appendices

Suppose I have a memoir-document with several chapters. At the end of each chapter, I want to include one or more appendices using

```
\namedsubappendices
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Foo1}
\section{Foo2}
\end{subappendices}
```

For example in Chapter 2, these would be called

```
Appendix 2.A Foo1
Appendix 2.B Foo2
```

However, I would prefer them to be called

```
Appendix A Foo1
Appendix B Foo2
```

That is, I would like to remove the chapter number from the appendix numbering. I suspect that this requires me to temporarily change the section numbering within each appendix but even this I wouldn't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply redefine `\thesection` within the `subappendices` environment:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\namedsubappendices
\begin{subappendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\section{One}
\section{Two}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```